# Почему иногда ссылки не открываются без www?

Tags: веб-программирование, http, ssl, https, браузер

Иногда при указании `www` в ссылке вместе с протоколом

```
https://www.somesite.com
```

браузер отказывается сразу на неё переходить, указывая:

```
SSL error: certificate issued for different hostname
```

И после согласия ссылка преобразуется в `https://somesite.com`.

А иногда наоборот: не указываешь `www`, а он добавляется в итоге (хотя ошибки в этом случае не бывает вроде).

С чем это связано? С неправильной конфигурацией на стороне сервера? Должен ли я как пользователь сайта при копипасте ссылок на его документы использовать тот адрес, что мне выдаст браузер после преобразования? Или могу всегда/никогда не использовать `www`?

Comment: «С неправильной конфигурацией на стороне сервера?» — да. Буковки www ничем не отличаются от других поддоменов и будут работать (или не работать) так, как будет настроен сервер. Иногда это даже может быть два разных сайта: например, сравните внешний вид [www.opennet.ru](https://www.opennet.ru) и https://opennet.ru

Comment: Настройте в .htaccess перенаправление с www на без www